# Tomcat: Single tomcat, multiple webapps with separate memory needs

Tags: tomcat

Its kind of a novice question but I thought I had to ask: Is it possible to host multiple webapps on a single tomcat instance so that each webapp has a separate memory (-Xms, -Xmx etc). We have multiple applications hosted on a single tomcat and one application sometimes receives huge amount of causing OutOfMemory issues.

The obvious solution is to host them separately but I am looking around for any other option if available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  It's really a JVM limitation that has nothing to do with Tomcat.  No possible way to "segment" a JVM like that.

I do some work with Apache Infrastructure (the team that runs apache.org).  There we typically front-end all Tomcat installations with a single Apache HTTPd server.  It allows us to:

- Bring individual Tomcat servers down for app or server upgrades
- Individually control the memory settings of each
- Give some processes higher/lower priority
- Identify "heavy" apps with plain linux/unix commands (top for example)
- Setup Nagios for more advanced monitoring

It's very convenient.